# StringIndexOutOfBound Exception

Tags: java

I was trying to write a program which takes a string from the user and tells the number of lowercase, upper case, white spaces etc. in the string to the user. But I get an error which says, StringIndexOutOfBound.

```
public class CharacterCount {
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Please enter you string here");
        String s = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(s);

        int upperCase = 0;
        int lowerCase = 0;
        int specialCase = 0;
        int whiteSpace = 0;
        int number = 0;

        for(int i=1;i<=s.length();i++)
        {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(ch))
            {
                if(Character.isUpperCase(ch))
                {
                    upperCase++;
                }
                else
                {
                    lowerCase++;
                }
            }

            if(Character.isWhitespace(ch))
            {
                whiteSpace++;
            }
            if(Character.isDigit(ch))
            {
                number++;
            }
            else
            {
                specialCase++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("The following are the results:");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(lowerCase+" :Lower Case Characters");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(upperCase+" :Upper Case Characters");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(whiteSpace+" :White Space");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(specialCase+" :Special Characters");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(number+" :Digits");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("----------------************THE END************------------------");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");

    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the exception? When you're asking a question which includes an exception, always show the full stack trace. Thanks for the complete program though.

Comment: i apologize. I will from next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are iterating over the wrong indices. Java indices start at 0, so a String of `length()` characters has indices from `0` to `length()-1`.

Your loop should be

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 for(int i=1;i<=s.length();i++)
```

You have to delete the "equals". That is why it is throwing an exception, you are simply going out of bounds of the string.
So the for loop should be `for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)`

Comment: and he should also start from 0 unless he/she is ignoring the first on purpose

Comment: Excuse me, I totally missed that, I guess I should go ahead and drink a cup of coffee!

Answer (score 1):

Your `for(int i=1;i<=s.length();i++)`

should be

```
for(int i=0;i < s.length();i++)
```

Arrays are zero-indexed , you start from 0 to the length - 1.

Answer (score 0):

Java Index starts from 0, so String size will never be more that length-1. So while looping use

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
```

or

```
for(int i=1;i<s.length()-1;i++)
```